# Salesforce - Eliminate the "Action" column in the support view

Tags: salesforce

The support view has the "Action" column. How do you disable it? The end users do not need this column, and it takes up so much space.

See screenshot

[image: http://f.cl.ly/items/1q2E2x1v223I0z2j0y45/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-22%20at%2012.43.26%20PM.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've successfully used Adblock plus to remove elements from the view. The action column has a unique class (x-grid3-td-ACTION_COLUMN) so if you add the rule ##td.x-grid3-td-ACTION_COLUMN it should remove the column.

Comment: This will only work for people who have installed AdBlock as well as the filter, if you want to inject Javascript into a standard page to do it: http://justinsilver.com/technology/salesforce/hide-edit-del-link-on-salesforce-standard-pages/